# Divide desktop into partitions?

Tags: desktop, icons

In my office PC desktop, because of high office load, I have lots of icons on my desktop.
Is there any portable software (for example : Stardock Fences : but it's not portable) which divides desktop / desktop wallpaper into small rectangles that I can put my icons refer to category? It is possible to do it manually by drawing rectangles on my wallpaper but I want it to be automated by a software.

Here is an example ;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although Stardock Fences is as close to being a one-of-a-kind of a program it possibly can be, there are actually *some* alternatives out there.

Here´s a piece of software you might like:

- [Desktop Contructor](http://se-soft.com/en/Products/DesktopConstructor/)

Comment: Instead of just downvoting, why not downvote _and_ explain why you didnt like my answer?

Comment: 1-I already know how to make a google search of "alternative stardock fences" and I think you don't understand what a "superuser" does , 2-desktop constructor does not fix my problem

Comment: "Teach a man to fish" does **not** work here, for one very important reason: StackExchange is a very popular site, and search queries will very often turn it up. SE is meant to be a repository for answers, not for "Google it"s, and by saying "Google it" you're actively polluting the results for googling it. I suggest you delete the answer, because it goes against everything SE stands for.

Comment: I think it is helpful because it _helps people find resources_. Besides, _I did **not** say 'google it'_, I said: 'go to these links, they contain some software you might find helpful'. And the 'fish'-thing is _actually what StackEchange is about._ You know, the whole "Explain things for other people and point them in the right direction". Which is what I did: Links to software he might think is suitable for this particular case: Check. Some healthy advice: Check. And since you _edited_ your question to say _Portable_, I know know that my answer wasn´t very suited for you.

Comment: @Marcus; Consider this scenario: Joe wants to know if a portable alternative to `Fences` exists, so he, as most would, googles it. In the results, probably at the top, is this question. The other results are other pages, which reference this question, with the same query. Even if your pointing produced good effects for @NT, by the time Joe was looking, things could have changed, and the results could have been polluted enough that your pointing was no longer accurate enough to help them. SU is meant to be a repository of knowledge, not a here-and-now. Pointing should be done in comments.

Comment: Which brings us to the question OP asked. Since SU is meant to be a repository of knowledge, a question asking for a particular program, which, as you said, _is a question asking for pointers_, again, as you said, _which very well may not be available at all when our Joe comes lurking about_, would not be _a valid question on SU_.